# Java error: can't find symbol?

Tags: java, string

I have the following code snippet where some strings are initialized in the `if` block:

```
String serialmask = request.getParameter( "serialmask"); 
String serialincrement = request.getParameter( "serialincrement");
if (serialmask == "1") { 
  String tserialmask = "aaa########"; 
} 
else { 
  String tserialmask = "";
}
if (serialincrement == "1") {  
  String tserialincrement = "aaa^^^^^^^^";
}
else { 
  String tserialincrement = ""; 
}
out.println(
  itemimport( 
    partnumber, 
    itemcost, 
    itemlistprice, 
    itemdescription, 
    PurchProdLineKey, 
    UnitMeasKey, 
    itemclasskey, 
    trackmethod, 
    tserialmask, 
    tserialincrement
  )
);
```

The error I'm getting is `"cannot find symbol"
symbol : variable tserialmask` in the `out.println(itemimport(....tserialmask,tserialincrement));` statement.

I tried declaring the variables outside of the `if` block and this seems to bring on even more errors saying it's already been declared.

Comment: Please give correctly formatted code. That is unreadable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare the variable first, but then just assign it. Here's the version for `tserialincrement` (the same is true for `tserialmask`)

```
String tserialincrement;
if (serialincrement == "1")
{
   tserialincrement = "aaa^^^^^^^^";
}
else
{ 
   tserialincrement = "";
}
```

However, there are two things wrong with this:

- You're using == on a string, which is a bad idea in almost all situations; use `equals`
- You can do it in one statement (per variable) with the conditional operator:

  ```
  String tserialmask = "1".equals(serialmask) ? "aaa########" : "";
  String tserialincrement = "1".equals(serialincrement) ? "aaa^^^^^^^^" : "";
  ```

In addition, I'd suggest nicer variable names, using Pascal casing (e.g. `serialMask`) and something more useful than just "t" as a prefix. (What does that mean?)

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare tserialmask and tserialincrement outside of the if/else blocks.  Otherwise, they go out of scope when that block ends.

```
String serialmask = request.getParameter( "serialmask");
String serialincrement = request.getParameter( "serialincrement");
String tserialmask;
String tserialincrement;

if (serialmask == "1")
{  
  tserialmask = "aaa########";
}
else
{ 
  tserialmask = "";
}
if (serialincrement == "1")
{
  tserialincrement = "aaa^^^^^^^^";
}
else
{ 
  tserialincrement = "";
}
out.println(itemimport(partnumber,itemcost,itemlistprice,itemdescription,PurchProdLineKey,UnitMeasKey,itemclasskey,trackmethod,tserialmask,tserialincrement));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring String variables within the if else statements then trying to access them outside the statements. You need to declare the variables before your if statements and then only assign them within the if/else statements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variables tserialmask and tserialincrement outside the if branches **and** not try to redeclare them inside, like this:

```
String tserialmask;
if (serialmask == "1") {  
    tserialmask = "aaa########"; 
} else { 
    tserialmask = ""; 
}
```